# Sphinx configuration of specific page

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm working on documentation for a network automation tool that consists of multiple products. I would like to display the version of the software in the header, but only on a specific page. I know that usually, this is possible by configuring it in **conf.py** specifically:

```
# The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags
release = ''
```

I can't use this, as it shows on all the pages and it's not relevant on most of them.

I tried to achieve it by using templates that sphinx supports, but from my understanding templates are made with HTML and don't affect the header of the page.

I also tried to add edited **conf.py** in the directories I want to affect, but it doesn't seem to work that way. I think I went through all Sphinx's documentation but couldn't find a good solution. I am using sphinx-rtd theme, maybe that will help. Thanks in advance

Pictures for illustration of my problem:

[image: Page layout]